# Can while be replaced with if if the function is not recursive?

Tags: java, algorithm, loops

I am following the course from coursera regarding Algorithms and I was just wondering whether one of the functions can be written in a much simpler way:

```
private int root ( int i)
{
  while( i != id[i])
    {
      id[i] = id[id[i]];
      i = id[i];
    }
   return i;
}
```

A really brief introduction is that the `id[]` represents an array of elements which are trees. All of the elements have a numerical value which points to the root. This function tries to find the root.

It works. However is there any need for the `while` loop? The function doesn't appear to be recursive nor increment the `i` in any way so can it be replaced by an `if` ?

I know I am missing something here but I just can't find what.

Comment: @TheLostMind: He/she is asking about its use in *this particular code*.

Comment: In this particular case, yes it can be changed to an IF statement just because of this line: `i = id[i];` so your `while` only will do one loop or none.

Comment: This code is meaningless without having the array `id` structured in a certain way. @Bula as for your question, it's indeed not recursive, it's iterative and no you can't switch the `while` with an `if` unless you're positive that for every scenario the loop will run only once.

Comment: @JorgeCampos A loop is needed, see my answer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yeah, its true, I missed the 0 as start. :) thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example, it is trying to find a path.  The loop isn't incrementing a variable instead it sets `i =` on each iteration to the next element in the path `id[i]`

Imagine the array looks like

```
int[] id = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4 };
int i = 0;
```

On the first iteraton,

```
i = 0;
i = id[0] == 1;
i = id[1] == 2;
i = id[2] == 3;
i = id[3] == 4;
4 == id[4] so it stops.
```

Loops which use something other than incrementing are fairly common, the most obvious example is using an Iterator, but another common example is traversing the nodes of a List.

Comment: Oh. I got confused with the way they do it in scala. I knew I was missing something. Thanks for quick answer.